# Me muestra lo siguiente "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\imprime.php on line 85"

Tags: php

Mi código trabaja con una clase donde recibe los valores de un form:
class Producto{

```
    public function __construct($num_recibo, $paciente,$dni,$direccion,$tipo_pago,$detalle,$precio){
        $this ->num_recibo=$_POST['num_recibo'];
        $this ->paciente=$_POST['paciente'];
        $this ->dni=$_POST['dni'];
        $this ->direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
        $this ->tipo_pago=$_POST['tipo_pago'];
        $this ->detalle=$_POST['detalle'];
        $this ->precio=$_POST['precio'];
    }
}
 $productos= array(
    new producto("num_recibo","paciente","dni","direccion","tipo_pago","detalle","precio")
 );
```

al llamar a los valores para imprimirlos me muestra el NOTICE aquí:

```
$printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer->text("Recibo: ".$productos->num_recibo. "\n");
$printer->text("Paciente: ".$productos->paciente. "\n");
$printer->text("Direccion: ".$productos->direccion. "\n");
$printer->text("Tipo de Pago: ".$productos->tipo_pago. "\n");
```

pero el $detalle y $precio si son reconocidos y no arrojan error

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    $total += 1 * $producto->precio;
    /*Alinear a la izquierda para la cantidad y el nombre*/
    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    $printer->text(1 . "x" . $producto->detalle . "\n");

    /*Y a la derecha para el importe*/
    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_RIGHT);
    $printer->text(' S/' . $producto->precio . "\n");
}// 
/*
    Terminamos de imprimir
    los productos, ahora va el total
*/
$printer->text("--------\n");
$printer->text("TOTAL: S/". $total ."\n");
```

Comment: Muestra el contexto completo explicando cada cosa para ver qué es lo que estás omitiendo.

Comment: tengo un formulario donde se toman los datos son pasados por método POST , estos van a un php que imprime un ticket, para esto tengo la clase que mencione arriba y recibe todos los valores(ya revise que si los manda y lee), al momento de querer imprimir $num_recibo, $paciente,$direccion y $tipo_pago me arroja la NOTICE pero mas baja llamo a $detalle y $precio y si los reconoce

Comment: Intentas obtener un dato con sintaxis de objeto bien de un `null` o de un *array*. El propio mensaje te indica la línea, es esta o la anterior.

Comment: pero en la parte de abajo donde llamo a $detalle y $precio realizo lo mismo mas alguna operación de suma y multiplicación y no me muestra ese error, solo aparece al querer imprimir los valores

Comment: Te lo explico en mi respuesta de más abajo. Con *detalle* y *precio* te funciona porque el `foreach` se mete dentro del array `$productos` y entonces si que puedes acceder a los atributos del objeto. Con `$productos->num_recibo` estás tratando de acceder a los atributos de un `array`, y no tiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
$productos= array(
    new producto("num_recibo","paciente","dni","direccion","tipo_pago","detalle","precio")
 );
```

Estás creando un `array` al que le estás metiendo dentro un **objeto**. Para poder acceder directamente a las propiedades de dicho objeto deberías hacer algo como:

```
$printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer->text("Recibo: ".$productos[0]->num_recibo. "\n");
$printer->text("Paciente: ".$productos[0]->paciente. "\n");
$printer->text("Direccion: ".$productos[0]->direccion. "\n");
$printer->text("Tipo de Pago: ".$productos[0]->tipo_pago. "\n");
```

Al hacer `$productos->num_recibo` estás tratando de acceder a un `array` (porque `$productos` es un `array`) como si se tratara de un objeto con la propiedad *num_recibo* y es lo que te ocasiona el *Notice*.

A *detalle* y *precio* accedes a través de un `foreach` en el que cada iteración corresponde a uno de los objetos que tenga ese `array`, por eso si que estás pudiendo acceder directamente a sus propiedades con `$producto->detalle` y `$producto->precio` respectivamente.

Comment: si haciendo eso si soluciona el error muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si te sirvió vota la respuesta como válida para que se considere resuelta  la pregunta^^